# how to display a scrolling Text ticker on a video played using textureview

Tags: android, android-layout, overlay, textureview

Iam playing a video using android textureview , my requirement is to add a text ticker at the bottom of the video, the ticker consists of a live 3d backgroundstrip over which text  scrolls . how to draw a live 3d background  at the bottom of the texture view  that is already playing a video ie., the ticker should be like an overlay to the video . I have tried calling the surface again and apply set tranform on it but the original video size is also change . Can some one please tell me howto go about. thank you

Comment: You can place other UI elements on top of the TextureView.  You don't need to put the text into the TextureView itself.

Comment: thank you  , yes i can use a textview over the video i'll get the text but like drawing  a 3d red ribbon as a background for the text is getting difficult. using the imageview i could place a red ribbon image on top of the textureview but my requirement is to make a 3d moving background red ribbon

Comment: Create a second TextureView, layer it on top of the first, render your ribbon into that.  Or play your video into a SurfaceTexture and then render the texture yourself.  (See e.g. "texture from camera" in Grafika, https://github.com/google/grafika .)

Comment: thankyou i'll take the first approach and refer to the example